# __init__.py imports expose also modules I use, not only my own classes

Tags: python, import, namespaces, package

There's something that I'm not grasping about python imports. I've read dozens of articles but I'm not finding a satisfactory answer. The situation is this:

I'm writing a package made of several modules. Let's say that the package is named `pack1`. In the `__init__.py` file, in order to expose the classes and functions I defined in my modules, I wrote:

```
    from .module1 import *
    from .module2 import *
    ...
```

Now, in module 1:

```
    from math import sqrt  # a tool that I need

    class class1:
         <body>

    class class2:
         <body>
    ....
    class class100:
         <body>
```

My problem is that when I

```
    import pack1
```

in another project, **I see `sqrt` in `pack1`'s namespace**. Do I have to import each one of the 100 classes separately in the `__init__.py` file in order to avoid this and keep my namespace clean? Do I have to do some hack with the inspect module in `__init__.py` in order to identify the classes that were defined and not imported (I think this would be very ugly)? Or, as I suspect, I'm mistaking something about how I should handle the module structure or the import statements?

Comment: Why wouldn't you? It *is* in that namespace. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

Comment: Yes, I expressed myself badly; I know that things are working exactly as intended, my question was how to do a clean wildcard import, since I want to import many names and import them explicitly would be tedious.

Comment: You are explaining one of the causes why wildcard imports are considered bad practice by many Python developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcard imports import *everything* defined in the global namespace in that module. It does not discriminate between "local" classes, modules that were imported, functions or variables.

There are two ways around this:

1. Import exactly what you want, instead of using wildwards. *Explicit is better than implicit*, according to `import this`.
2. Use the special `__all__` variable to define exactly what should be imported when the module is wildcard-imported. See [Can someone explain __all__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)

Comment: The `__all__` variable was the piece that I was missing to elegantly handle wildcard imports. Thank you very much!